# assertArrayEquals not working in Junit

Tags: java, junit

I am having issues with my assertArrayEquals in java. It is asking me to create a new method but i am using JUnit so I don't really understand how i can fix this issue.

This is my Junit test case

```
    @Test
    public void testSortInsert() throws IOException {
        Word tester1 [] = input(0,16);
        Word tester2 [] = input(1,256);
        Word tester3 [] = input(2,256);
        Insertion.sortInsert(tester1);

        Word insert1 [] = input(0,16);
        StopWatch time = new StopWatch();
        time.start();
        Insertion.sortInsert(insert1);
        time.stop();
        int insertTime = timer(time);
        assertArrayEquals(insert1,tester1);
    }
```

This is my word file which has my Word ADT. It includes a @overide for equals

```
package sort;

public class Word implements Comparable<Word>{
    private String word;
    private int score;

    public Word(String w, int s)
    {
        this.word = w;
        this.score = s;
    }

    public Word() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int getScore()
    {
        return this.score;
    }

    public void setScore(int s)
    {
        this.score = s;
    }

    public String getWord()
    {
        return this.word;
    }

    public void setWord(Word w)
    {
        this.word = w.word;

    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Word w)
    {
        if (this.score > w.score){
            return 1;
        }
        if (this.score < w.score){
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x)
    {
        if (this == x) { return true; }
        if (x == null) { return false; }
        if (getClass() != x.getClass()) { return false; }
        Word other = (Word) x;
        if (score != other.score) { return false; }
        if (word == null) 
        {
            if (other.word != null) { return false; }
            else if (!word.equals(other.word)) { return false; }
        }
        return true;
    }


    public String toString()
    {
        //TODO
        return "{" + this.word + "," + this.score + "}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `assertArrayEquals` defined?

Comment: Its a built in function in java that works with array of ints and strings. I just want it to work with array of type word

Comment: @immibis It's a method from the JUnit framework.

Answer (score 3):

Import the static methods in the org.junit.Assert class:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

or use the class name:

```
Assert.assertArrayEquals(insert1,tester1);
```

Comment: Thank you this works, I didnt have import static org.junit.Assert.*;

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JUnit 4 (as it looks like you are), you presumably aren't extending an existing test class - so you need to call the static `assertArrayEquals` with the class name, e.g.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
...
Assert.assertArrayEquals(...);
```

Now, that ends up being a bit clunky, so often developers statically import the methods they want, e.g.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;
...
assertArrayEquals(...);
```

or just import everthing:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
...
assertArrayEquals(...);
```